# How did they get from the third matrix to the fourth one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My book just did that without explanation and I can't see how it has been done.
It looks like they multiplied R3 by (a+2) but I can't see how it makes a[3,2] 0 .

[image: referring to this matrix]

Comment: $\rho_e = \rho_3-(1+a) \rho_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling $R$ as the designed row, just do

$$R_3 - (1+a)R_2$$

That means: take the third row, and subtract from it the product of $(1+a)$ times the second row.

Indeed

$$(1-a^2) - (1-a)(1+a) = 1-a^2 - 1-a^2 = 0$$

$$(1-a) - (1+a)(a-1) = 1-a+1-a^2 = 2-a-a^2 = (1-a)(a+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

They use following operations in step you marked.

$R_{2} - R_{1}$ and $R_{3} - aR_{1}$

And in last step

$R_{3} - (1 + a)R_{2}$

The notation I used above in this type of notation first term represent the row or column on which we are applying operation.

> Or you can use more specific notation.

$R_{2} \to R_{2} - R_{1}$ and $R_{3} \to R_{3} - aR_{1}$

And in last step

$R_{3} \to R_{3} - (1 + a)R_{2}$

Comment: I get what you're saying, or at least what I think you're trying to say.  If we are looking at the second to the third matrix, we have: "Add $-R_1$ to  $R_2$.  Then add $-aR_1$ to $R_3$, to get the third matrix.

Comment: @amWhy the book from which I read matrices. In that book operations are always in the above form as first element shows the terms on which we are apply operation.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I did not downvote this answer.)  Kanwaljit - I think explaining the actions you're taking; your English is fine.  Your answer is correct; but it did take me awhile to understand your notation, and I'm very familiar with the topic.  Anyway, you shouldn't have been downvoted, in my humble opinion.

Comment: I understand that.  But for the sake of a student who is very new to the subject, your answer may have been more helpful to the OP if you had defined how your notation is to be understood.  Since the notation for all of us amounts to shorthand for "documenting" our actions, those "shorthands" are not universal.  Sometimes it is best to be explicit, (in hopes it helps understanding of the OP), even though, e.g.,with other more experienced users, you'd be understood as is.

Comment: @amWhy then plz tell me how to -> this type of arrow.

Comment: You can use either `\to` or `\rightarrow` to get $\to,\; \rightarrow$ respectively.  And, you can use `\longrightarrow` which gives $\longrightarrow$ for a longer arrow.  For future reference, you can use `\leftarrow` and `\longleftarrow` to get $\leftarrow$ or $\longleftarrow$, respectively.

Comment: Also, you've written $R_{2} \to R_{2} - R_{1}$ and $R_{3} \to R_{3} - aR_{1}$ I would switch directions: $(R_2-R_1) \to R_2,$ and $\;R_3-aR_1 \to Row_3$, respectively. We operate on two rows, $ R_i, R_j$ to replace one of them.